# Excel powerpivot parent-child hierarchy

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I'm new to powerpivot excel 2013 and I have a question. I have parent child hierarchy in my table. Can I substract child values fro there parents using powerpivot?

Thanks in advance for support

Comment: can you please share a screenshot how your dataset looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to create calculations to get the correct scope with DAX.  Here is a good article: http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/scoping-at-different-granularities-part-iii/

You can get the total of the parent and get the total for the child and subtract.